# Create checkbox bigger

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I have a question regarding this way of solving the problem. I need a bigger check box. Partial solution of the problem writer in a method:

```
private JCheckBox createCheckBox() {
    Icon normal = new ImageIcon(...);
    Icon selected = new ImageIcon(...);
    JTable table = new JTable(what parameter);
    table.setRowHeight(...);

    TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class);
    JCheckBox checkBoxRenderer = (JCheckBox)renderer;
    checkBoxRenderer.setIcon( normal );
    checkBoxRenderer.setSelectedIcon( selected );

    DefaultCellEditor editor = (DefaultCellEditor)table.getDefaultEditor(Boolean.class);
    JCheckBox checkBoxEditor = (JCheckBox)editor.getComponent();
    checkBoxEditor.setIcon( normal );
    checkBoxEditor.setSelectedIcon( selected );
    return which panel?
}
```

### Two questions

1. Which panel should I return if I want to add this panel to my mail panel?
2. What parameter can a give in the constructor for `JTable table = new JTable(...);`?

Comment: You need a bigger check box so you're creating a `JTable`?  You could just specify the icons for a `JCheckBox` and return that instead

Comment: ***"Two questions"***  SO is not a help desk, but a Q&A site where each thread should be a single question.  That helps people to find it later.

Comment: Alos consider a custom `TableCellEditor` using a `JToggleButton`.

Comment: Question for MadProgrammer?
Can you please write to me the correct way of writing the method?
I guess I ve done something wrong, my checkbox is not shown. Thank you .